# Inter VLAN Routing Issue

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan

Here's what I have setup

3 Networks across 3 switches (3x C3650)

- 10.7.64.x/24 (Vlan 7)
- 10.10.10.x/24 (Vlan 20)
- 192.168.1.x/24 (Vlan 15)

The switches are all connected to each other, with Switch one have a connection to an ASA and the outside world.  My goal is to get all three switches communicating via Layer 2 by using the 10.10.10.x network as a bridge to connect the other two networks.

Each switch has one switchport that exists in the 10.10.10.x network (.1 for Switch 1, .2 for Switch 2, .3 for Switch 3).

I currently have a route in Switch 1 that is as follows:

`ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.3`

I have a route in Switch 3 that is as follows:

`ip route 10.7.64.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1`

From the 192.168.1.x network I can ping everything perfectly in the 10.10.10.x and 10.7.64.x networks.  However, I can ONLY `ping` the SVI for VLAN 15 (192.168.1.1) and the network id (192.168.1.0) from the 10.7.64.x network on Switches 1&2.

Right now there is a trunk between Switches 1&2 and a trunk between Switches 1&3.  On both trunks Vlan access is being granted to Vlans 7,20 and 15.

This really has me stumped as to why I can't have complete bi-directional communication.  Can anyone assist me in this?

Comment: Routers connect networks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mess in your head. A really big one.

- you do not need the network A and B to be reachable through C.
- you do not need the switch in C network to be the route for A.

What you need, is a router, which will have interfaces in all of your networks, and this router should be a *default gateway* for all three networks.

ASA could probably be such a router, but that's not perfect, because using ASA as a router will have a negative impact sooner or later.

Comment: It is true for what I had going on a router would have been handy.  However, what I am going for is to wall of my SAN, which will live on the 192 network from the rest of my network and still retain the ability to remotely manage the SAN.  SW1&2 are currently in use for the general network of my office and have default routes pointing towards our ASA and the net.  SW3 until now has been cut off from the rest of the network as it was not really in use.

Comment: Im echoing Drookie, you need a router to route between all 3 networks. To that end, the 3650 is a L3 switch. Are you saying that 192.168.1.0/24 is only connected (vlan interface?) on SW3 and 10.7.64.0/24 only on SW1. Who is the gateway on the 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.7.64.0/24 network?

Comment: I simplified the setup and got it all working.  Thanks for taking the time to offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified my setup by removing vlan 20 and having vlans 15 and 7 live on SW1.  After doing this the final key was issuing the "vlan 15" command from global config so that a L2 vlan would build under the SVI I had.  Life is now good. :)